# How can we use Daikon Invariant Detector to find the invariants from a data provided in CSV file?

Tags: java, csv, invariants

I am trying to find the invariants from a data set (.csv file) using Daikon but I didn't find any example or help over the internet to run daikon on .CSV file containing boolean data (matrix of 3 by 8).
[Image for the csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0z9s.png)

As instructions provided in daikon user manual, I run the convercsv.pl to convert .dtrace and .decls files corresponding to my csv file, which are used to apply the daikon, but it prints few lines of data and gives error "TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE at convertcsv.pl line 380,  line 1.LSE".
[error while converting the csv dtrace and decls files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UauQQ.png)

Comment: It's a shot in the dark without seeing the code of the scripts you are using, but could it be that your csv is separating fields with semicolon while your scripts expect some other character (such as comma) ? But really, without seeing the code, it could be literally anything.

Comment: Please provide a small .csv file that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the help. It worked as I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone. The problem is solved. The problem was with the CSV file. The code was unable to read automatically saved CSV file. I just replaced the end of line (by clicking backspace and enter) at the end of each record in text editor. By simply replacing end of line I was able to convert csv file to .dtrac and decls files. After creating it I simply run the daikon on dtrac and decls files and it produced the invariants.

Source code of daikon can be found at http://plse.cs.washington.edu/daikon/download/doc/daikon.html
It had only problem which I mentioned above about converting the csv file into .dtrac and .decls files, rest works fine.